# SignalR: Hub OnConnected not called if no client methods

Tags: javascript, signalr, signalr-hub, signalr.client

I am writing a game in SignalR. The idea is that you connect with your laptop, which will be used as "display" and then you connect with your smart phone and that will be used as "joystick". The entire setup works very well.

Now that it all works, I decided to refactor the code. I realized that the relationship between the joystick and the display is one way (the display never needs to send information back to the joystick). Therefore I decided that I did not need any signalR invokable client functions on the joystick (e.g. there is no use for `gameHub.client.joyStickMethod()` in the joystick js.

*It was then I discovered something strange*

It turns out that hub method `public override Task OnConnected()` that I override to deal with the different types of clients (displays and joysticks) is not invoked unless I define a `myHub.client.clientSideMethod()`. Here's the example I'm dealing with:

```
        var gameHub = $.connection.gameHub;
        gameHub.client.connection();
        $("#joystick").joystick({
            hub: gameHub
        });

        gameHub.client.activateJoystick = function () { };
        $.connection.hub.qs = "type=joystick&gameId=" + "@Model.Id";
        $.connection.hub.start();   //this will invoke on connected
```

You see that empty client side method? That's the reason why `OnConnected` is called on server side. If I remove that line of code, it will not be called.

```
        var gameHub = $.connection.gameHub;
        gameHub.client.connection();
        $("#joystick").joystick({
            hub: gameHub 
        });

        //gameHub.client.activateJoystick = function () { };
        $.connection.hub.qs = "type=joystick&gameId=" + "@Model.Id";
        $.connection.hub.start();   //this will invoke on connected
```

This will not work, since there is no client side method on the Hub. I can probably add a `RegistrateJoystick`method on the Hub and call that, but I think that the behavior is unexpected. My question is therefore:

**Is there a way to manually "connect" to the hub, so that the `OnConnect` method will be called?**

Answer (score 14):

That's by design. If you don't have any subscriptions to the hub then that particular client can't won't get any messages from server to client. You can still invoke methods on the hub.

Comment: Thanks for you answer. I understand the logic in what you're saying, but at the same time, the name of the server side method "OnConnect" sounds to me that it would be called no matter if your client has invokable methods or not.

Comment: Sure, but that's not how it works. And the method is OnConnected.

Comment: Just to echo what pardahlman said its a bit non-intuitive given the naming, might be worth calling it out pretty explicitly in docs to avoid confusion.

Comment: It would be great if you added some example code. Note section in [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/signalr/overview/guide-to-the-api/hubs-api-guide-javascript-client#how-to-establish-a-connection) is poor for this

Answer (score 1):

A way around this is to just have a fake Hub that you wire up to.  Does nothing, returns void.  At least this way, when you bootstrap your game, before you call .start() on the connection, you wire up to this fake method on the fake hub.  This will get you the onConnected() method.

I agree, this is such odd behaviour.  If you make a connection, onConnected() should be raised, even if you're not listening to events.

What makes this even more odd is if you're doing Hub authorization.  If you derive from the AuthorizeAttribute, in your case, the AuthorizeHubMethodInvokation() will be called for each method you call on the client, but the AuthorizeHubConnection() will never be called.

--Update

I played around with this on my project.  I had the iniital idea of creating a hub proxy on the client that doesn't exist on the server, but this fails.  However, you can just hook up to a *real* hub but a fake callback.  This does work and lets you get away with creating a real method.

This is clearly a horrible work around, but in the face of nothing else, does the job.

Answer (score 0):

As pardahlman says, we need to register an event before OnConnected and OnDisconnected work.

```
connection = $.hubConnection("http://localhost:9002");

var proxy = connection.createHubProxy("testHub");

//without this on listener, OnConnected and OnDisconnected doesn't raise.
proxy.on("messageToClients", (message) => {

});

await connection.start(function () {
    console.log("Connected");
})
```

Microsoft documentation mention it, but is very difficult to fine that note.

[image]
[image]