# SignalR. Cant reach OnConnected()

Tags: javascript, c#, signalr-hub, signalr.client

Hub-code

```
public class TestHub : Hub
    {
        public void Message(string message)
        {
                Clients.Group("testGroup").displayMessage(message);
        }
        public override Task OnConnected()
        {
            Groups.Add(Context.ConnectionId, "testGroup");
            return base.OnConnected();
        }
    }
```

Javascript Code with generated Proxy

```
var myHub = $.connection.testHub;
myHub.on('message', this.displayMessage);

$.connection.hub.start();



function displayMessage(message) {
 console.log(message);
}
```

If I do the above it seems like the hub.start() is running correctly and it returns some form of object. But when i debug with a breakpoint inside OnConnected I never hit.

Any suggestions?

Comment: You are missing some code. Look at this https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR/issues/1065

Comment: Thought it was the same as myHub.on('message', this.displayMessage); Or am I missing something ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Basiclly, you can invoke hub methods but the OnConnect won't work if you don't have subscriptions on the hub. 
It's weird but that's the way it works.

Do it like this:

```
var myHub = $.connection.testHub;

//add subscriptions
$.extend(myHub.client, {
    stupidLogicSignalR: function () {}
});

myHub.on('message', this.displayMessage);
$.connection.hub.start();
```

[Here's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14273949/signalr-hub-onconnected-not-called-if-no-client-methods) a similar question.
Also this [issue](https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR/issues/1065) can help

Comment: $.extend is an alternate way to define method on client (with the generated proxy)
it can be like :
myHub.client.stupidLogicSignalR=function(){};

Answer (score 0):

Worked with other syntax for the subscribe

```
myHub.client.displayMessage = () => {console.log('message');};
```

Comment: Didn't my answer help you in this matter? The line you use is doing exact same thing as I told you to add.

Answer (score 0):

enable logging at front end by(do it after `var myHub = $.connection.testHub;`):

```
$.connection.hub.logging = true;
```

or assign a callback to .start by:

```
$.connection.hub.start().done(function () {
console.log("connection started")
});
```